# Directed Graph Representation in HTML

Tags: javascript, java, json, graph, treeview

I have stored a graph in a Java data structure which maps a node to a node list. The graph is more likely a tree structure. I want to represent the graph in a HTML page like a tree view. I can convert the data structure to JSON format and send to a JavaScript function. The general view of the tree is like the following.

```
    A
   / \
  B   C
 / \   \
D   E   F
 \ /
  G
  |
  H
```

Comment: Check out d3.js: a very powerful JS library that can make a lot of beautiful graph. Like this: http://nlpviz.bpodgursky.com/home, or this: https://mohansun-canvas.herokuapp.com/content/training/.
Plenty of examples here: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery
But learning d3.js takes time, please consider.

Answer (score 2):

You could create your own graphing code, but D3 (http://d3js.org) has some excellent tree graphing.

Examples:
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tree-Layout

http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8375092

Answer (score 2):

Try out the Force-Directed graph ([here's an example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045)) you can create using http://d3js.org